# When I try to change a color everything become purple

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to change RGB color in GIMP, simple open "Change Foreground Color" 
and setting new RGB values, but when I set the number in the R field the color become purple, why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried to take a color which is impossible to show in RGB. GIMP has at least a possiblity to select impossible to display colors by Lightness-Chroma-Hue. LCH easily allows combinations which are undisplayable in RGB monitors (=need RGB numbers beyond the available range 0....255) Those combinations are shown as bright magenta.

Reduce Chroma (=colorfulness, =deviation from grayscale)  to displayable range. (=activate LCH sliders instead of HSV and decrease C). See, how the RGB numbers become to allowed range. Maximum available chroma is possible for pure R, G or B, mixed colors must have less.